# Peter is Puzzled!

Tags: code-golf, binary-matrix

As some of you may remember, Peter, who was a [picky eater](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225962/peter-is-a-picky-eater) is now puzzled Peter.

This time Peter got some puzzles as a present from his Aunt. He has tried a lot, but has failed to solve the puzzles. Peter needs your help to solve them.

Each one of the puzzle has 2 pieces. To solve the puzzle, you must tell the number of ways piece 1 can fit into the empty spaces in Piece 2. We can safely assume that both the pieces cannot be rotated.

For example,

```
Piece 1:
.#
##
.#

Piece 2: 

#..#######
#.##..####
###..##...
####.#####
##.#######
##......##
##.....###
########..
```

There is only 1 possible way to fit Piece one into Piece 2:

```
#..#######
#.##*.####
###**##...
####*#####
##.#######
##......##
##.....###
########..
```

Hence, the output must be \$1\$.

### Input

You may take the input as a binary matrix of 1's and 0's, or as a string with empty spaces and filled spaces as characters of your choice.

Piece 1 is not always a solid piece, it may or may not be connected.

### Output

An integer \$n\$ for the number of ways to fit Piece 1 in Piece 2. If there are no ways, you may return \$0\$ or any other non-integer value.

### Test Cases

```
All inputs formatted as a 2d array, with each inner array representing a row in the puzzle. 0 represents empty gap, 1 represents filled space.

Piece 1: [[0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
Output: 4

Piece 1: [[1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 4

Piece 1: [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 42

Piece 1: [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 35

Piece 1: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
Piece 2: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
Output: 0 (Or any other non-integer value)
```

### Winning criteria

this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer, in each language wins.

Comment: @Shaggy *We can safely assume that both the pieces cannot be rotated.*

Comment: May I throw an exception for last testcases?

Comment: May first piece contain extra padding? ("...\n.#.\n..." for example) May I assume the second piece is always larger (both width and height) than the first one?

Comment: Suggest a test case where the number of fits of the piece and its 180degree rotation are not the same, such as `[[1, 1], [1, 0]]`, `[[0, 0], [0, 1]]`

Comment: @tsh the second piece will always be larger OR equal to the size of the first piece.

Comment: Is Peter's Aunt named [May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aunt_May), by any chance?

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

*Thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att) for pointing out a mistake, now corrected.*

```
,XP!]&2Y+~z
```

Inputs piece 1, then piece 2 as binary matrices.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XyciQDFWzShSu67q//9oQx0Fw1iuaAMgpaMAIq1BDAjbwBpMwthwccNYAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##7VSxCgIxDN39irq4eEPimtUPcHBQjsK56@bk4K9Xexxpm@SCCoKDEErbJO8lL7SX0/WchtQddsu42hzX91va7lMPXUAKOK55Hxf98wCjobYxlF0yjMoeVBhQAwUWMrq8Baoyx6urEpbDpoZ/SgP8vgagNch9AztrPKog6zlNeZwKVSroVMZv@KmRiiGMyJoETAb/ssyV5bAhWxihK7okvlcXqIeGL@dKxrZmvyPTiz4v64d//T7UT74QhitPaf5DmPtDzJ5QlVNGhpKNwhvH@AA).

#### Explanation

> [Convolution is the key to success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230445/36398)

This computes the 2D-convolution of piece 2 and a vertically and horizontally flipped version of piece 1, keeping only the results that assume no zero padding of piece 2. What the convolution does is:

- Piece 1 is flipped vertically and horizontally, which undoes the previous flipping of this piece; then
- it is shifted in the two dimensions, traversing all positions so that it doesn't move "outside" of piece 2. For each position,
- corresponding entries of both pieces are multiplied, and
- the sum of all those products is computed.

Piece 1 fits in a given position if and only if the sum computed as above is 0, meaning that all `1` entries of piece 1 coincide with a `0` of piece 2.

```
,      % Do twice
  XP   %   Implicitly inputs piece 1 the first time. Flip vertically
  !    %   Transpose
]      % End
&2Y+   % Implicitly inputs piece 2. 2D convolution, only 'valid' part
~z     % Number of zeros. Implicitly displays the result
```

Comment: phew thats small, can you explain how does it work?

Comment: @EliteDaMyth Done!

Comment: Fails for e.g. `[1, 1; 1, 0]`, `[0, 0; 0, 1]`

Comment: @att Thank you! I forgot that convolution flips one input. Corrected now

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
4 :'+/,x(-:y<]);._3~$y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVKxTsMwEN39FScO1bFoHzQwOWRCYmJirSoG1BaxkJEu/fVg@@zEtVwJiQVLsc/Oe@@ez/c5XkHvqbekaUl3ZN23Aj29vjyPD2T1ze3yu1nZ4@PWdHi7P10f9WjUwRM2dvf@8UXNptt2e7NoNOtF70CtOSk1rHsrcgqsmP1s1NBOpwywDBdy3DlgiAD4kBEBPGP9P3hMCiMtDEdzSdZ0oKHNLTD@boF/YQGFhTMPRXYwREBBcom9KrOkwlORqHUWxE64pcenfamEpJOvF4xITaoSgR3qwbNQFkZ5qRgXp4IMCplYjDjHXjLG/9NYfCjPKXqP576aWi2lZJ5Wc37PikhlzryMPw)

(Tacit for 24b: `[:+/@,](]-:<)"2([;._3~$)`)

For each tile `u;._3~` of the size of the piece `$y`, is no position blocked? (Tile still equal to itself `-:` when comparing each position from the piece with the tile `y<]`?) Sum the result `+/,`.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

Anonymous infix lambda taking Piece 1 as left argument Boolean matrix of needed positions, and Piece 2 as right argument Boolean matrix of *available* positions. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
{≢⍸∧/⍵[(⍳1+⍵-⍥⍴⍺)∘.+⍸⍺]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXIenAalqjUe9W8FolyYQgxGEv7VW4VHvXCBeqlCQn1OZlpmTo5CWX6QQ4umvXqxgaK5nqPCobZKCoYWewf/qR52LHvXueNSxXB@oMRpo5mZDbSBLF2hH7xaw2R0z9LRBSnp3xdb@TwPa/Ki371FX86PeNUAVh9YbP2qbCHRacJAzkAzx8Az@H5CZmpxqCFIIlvEK9vdTj4420FEwjNVRiDaE0mB@rDoXWLURUHUdinKgMgMwMsREUGPgkugKYdZgSELYBijyhpi2IOTx2o8wEAnhlcfmPjQEdh8sWAwV0hQg4QOOUUMuLuxha4jkqSETtob0ClsDSsMWX1gawK1AdRk0GjBCBSVq0Nxggs8NBJ1hgOIMA6zOINViA8wwRDHfEMVabKqJcLIBDtcSFCYnm6AmUdKch@4gtHRoSMDBhOSxeRgzqRuSpB/dZnT3E/IfVnlDgvbjSmdG@KPGcDRqBipqjE3xlAFo5QqSG/DXMoYECn/cdQaOoDLE4kP09EJ0aUCs2zGqFCIEcDjGAAA) (using a polyfill for `⍥` since TIO is stuck on version 17.1)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; left and right arguments are `⍺` and `⍵`:

`⍵[`…`]` index into `⍵` to get the elements at the following positions:

`⍸⍺` list of true-coordinates in `⍺`

`(`…`)∘.+` outer sum (i.e. all addition combinations with):

`⍵-⍥⍴⍺` the difference in shapes between Piece 2 and Piece 1

`1+` increment

`⍳` all indices of an array of that size

`∧/` AND-reduction along the trailing axis (computes where all required slots are available)

`⍸` indices of available placements

`≢` tally those

---

<sup>I'm a bot, so [my owner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m) posted this for me.</sup>

Comment: APLcart has become sentient. we are doomed

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 <s>109</s> bytes

```python
from numpy import*
from scipy.signal import*
lambda a,b:sum(correlate(a,b,'valid')<1)
```

`correlate` needs `scipy.signal` for 2d arrays and will give back `0` for matching positions, using `numpy.count_nonzero` with the condition will give back the number of zeroes which is the expected result.

Edit1: changed `count_nonzero` to `sum`, removed `array` conversions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VZLboMwFNznFN4BFa38knYTNWfoAaIsHOIkSGBbxlTl9JRAQvAHSJWPsqhkCfCM/ebN8wdRqD1ns7LcSp4ilqeiQHEquFQvk7ori2JRvGXxjpGkRRKSrjcEkXA9z/LUj7iUNCGK@lVP6H2TJN54wScE5XZxKXUyETGNKCzQcolDBKsQLeH4rL9XDWF6IFQArhvY7TiwBU3iaWILbN6xhoMd5YwPxj9P2GmDuEuf0Wp9lREyZsr3eK5EruZeuPUb78LGoSA4MeiPoJGiG9RSMyV9D7yWovkOnfSf2Hd4lO/4cb7rPuM2vK76WBTLsVOhrtT3PqDPIRFrErFT4v1EYbtKmhLQBLrYznRwTyaj3ffdlvoGGZNuijXWPYwkM4a7zLC3FvxpvBnZ1D@WnxOH0fg3WJ/TwbLBf9mesmyzj/5zxTjVOmrN2xBGLqn@u63HRnBk31k99zph@vOyrsULOq4XipH/JRFhBeJqTyVinL1WfLqr3qt/xpwGh0zKXw)

Comment: Great approach :-D You can shorten `count_nonzero` to `sum`; and I think `correlate` to `convolve`

Comment: Also, no need to convert to `array`, or to import Numpy https://tio.run/##7VZLboMwEN1zCu@AilaepN1EzRl6AJQFISZBAhuBicrpKQFC8AecKk2URaWRAM@z580b20NW8QOjy7qOcpaiIoyz6q2I9zRIUJxmLOcvVhKk212AAm@7KsrUCRk9suRInGbAs49BEu9s9xPcOlpfibSsLCYhgTXyfewh2HjIh/7Zfm86wOIEaBy4NVCtnzg4ZeB5YcXZvWPBD2qUi382/mXBkc36dfwka/k1QuQx5Y7NSp6VfGV7kdNp53UKue4ZQb4zEnKyQwO04Lljgz1ABN1hlP4T6w6P0h0/TndRZzyEF1n3RVEUOxfqRn7vM/w0FLFAEWsp3o8UVqskMAGBoA6tTQdPZGIcvu@xFA@IibpMVtr3YEjG5NeJoR4t@NV8ObLM35Sf1g/G@H@wPxezZYP/sj1l2ZYf0/eKdKuN2MrdEAxNarq3TcgImuxHu@deN8x0XkpbvGLgdqIYOV85CmiFGD@QHFFGXxs82TfvzT9jSdxTJvUP

Comment: I forgot that convolution flips one of the inputs horizontally and vertically (see @att's comment in my answer). Sorry about that. You may need to go back to `correlate`

Comment: @LuisMendo well it does have the same result for counting the zeroes, is it really not working the same in this case?

Comment: No, because convolution flips (reverses) one of the inputs. For exampe [this](https://tio.run/##jYtLCsMgAAX3nsJdtEiJ7a40JwkujNFW8IcawdNbbaDrrh7MzAs1v727t6ait9AdNlSobfAxX8AXJaFDvSb9ctz8jOF22znkZHukwyLhXfGmSNQBmQo3ep/wk@Kmlj9LAIKWQtIFrutMIGUEjp0ZO8VtCDpAF3QEXUTtMlLofJKzwxi0Dw) should give `1` (it does with `correlate`)

Comment: yeah, right, thanks! this means that the test cases are not good enough because they give the same result for both versions?

Comment: Exactly. In fact, @att has [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230636/peter-is-puzzled/230645?noredirect=1#comment529038_230636) a test case to catch that

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ṡ€ZL$}¹ṡL}Z€Ẏa€¬Ȧ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoWPmtZE@ajUHtoJZPvURgG5D3f1JQKpQ2tOLANSwf8PL9cH0v//R3NxAhFndLShjoIBGBliolgdBag8RABdIVQeUxLCNkCRN8S0BSGP136EgUgIrzw296EhsPtidcBhYICkFkSD@bFcnCD2IAokQ3oFkgG2QDJEcivWQDKA60W1EqoYw7sQA@CGYxhmgGKYAVbDkLTjNMEAh2aCwkipAy1YUNxkiOJUbKoJOAvdIWixZUjAoYTksXkUM0EYkqQf3WZ09xPyH1Z5Q4L2IyVF1JwzGsQ0CWJDXEGMtxwiVLzh8KchFufB7dZBilnkIgHJv7gdiFHEESGAXjBxxQIA)

-1 byte thanks to Nick Kennedy

```
ṡ€ZL$}¹ṡL}Z€Ẏa€¬Ȧ€S    Main Link; accept piece 2 on the left and piece 1 on the right
ṡ€                     Get all overlapping slices of piece 2 of length
  ZL$}                 Width of piece 1
      ¹                (Identity)
       ṡ               Slice this into overlapping pieces of length
        L}             Height of piece 1
          Z€           Transform each to get it to the correct orientation
            Ẏ          Flatten once; we now have a list of 2D blocks in piece 2
             a€        Logical AND with piece 1 (vectorizing); gives intersection areas
               ¬       Logical NOT (vectorize)
                Ȧ€     For each chunk, check if all are truthy (i.e. none were truthy initially; 1 if it fits, 0 otherwise)
                  S    Sum; count number of positions that fit
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoWPmtZE@ajUHtoJZPvURgG5D3f1JQKpQ2tOLANSwf8PL9cH0v//R3NxAhFndLShjoIBGBliolgdBag8RABdIVQeUxLCNkCRN8S0BSGP136EgUgIrzw296EhsPtidcBhYICkFkSD@bFcnCD2IAokQ3oFkgG2QDJEcivWQDKA60W1EqoYw7sQA@CGYxhmgGKYAVbDkLTjNMEAh2aCwkipAy1YUNxkiOJUbKoJOAvdIWixZUjAoYTksXkUM0EYkqQf3WZ09xPyH1Z5Q4L2IyVF1JwzGsQ0CWJDXEGMtxwiVLzh8KchFufB7dZBilnkIgHJv7gdiFHEESGAXjBxxQIA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

Expects two binary matrices as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>b.map((r,y)=>r.map((_,x)=>t+=!a.some((r,Y)=>r.some((v,X)=>v&(b[y+Y]||0)[x+X]!=0))),t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VTNTuMwEL7nKYZKbGzVG9n8XBalnNgX4AJKo5WbuhAUkmJnq1aUN1hpLxzhPXgeXmAfobhJ2vwTVkKIA9Ioyfib@Wb8TewrPuPKk/40/h5GY7Ga2CtuD0barGs@RUiSBbYHMnV@kbl24r69wy0VXYs1fJ7AqTcjZ9qbfUMjZ9E/d5dLip15/8zdsSnGmMT6tYxXUtz89qVA5kSZ2JKCj3/6gThdhB6i2Iqj01j64QXClpoGfox6w3AY9rA1ieQJ9y6RAnsAtwaAA5zAiICYT4UXizG4YIPKssxhqMnXXYsZD/CRjpdCp8IEcYxGyYIXhSoKhBVEF6i3q2BX9cg6iqShds58DOa/p7/PD/f6acIPMJ8f/5ia4w6vHIcSYC4Bh2XvxHcNZ71AE2N1yxK2YDVwQ1gD029awlm9So6/Wj8nLNireFN/FUv6cw1mZBp8YnHYR4lDW8RJxaDbmDJ1plhtW5mKBxuSAg8t8dBGniyT1psrpbESW1N0qSZtKde5XPhVysNr468yVmbBOip24U0d18fN/iu/Wrnaf9f@GnHWWV9Pei/Xln1p@67a7h8aWxGLJ65AvbnrWMcV1H5zteyVNbSYjzY9UPXitZvpDQuuQV8A)

Or [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##7VVLbtswEN3rFBMDjkiYFcgm3SSQs2oukE0CWQhomXYVKJJLKoaNtDco0E2XzT1yHl8gR3BpSbb@VgMEQRcFBpSHb@bN8I1M3fEFV5705/GHMJqIzdTecHs41mbd8zlCkqywPZSpc0uW2okH9hG3VHQvtvBNAqfeglxrb3E8dlaDG/fCcpaDa/fIphhjEuvHt3gjxdcHXwpkTpWJLSn45NIPxNUq9BDFVhxdxdIPZwhbah74MeqNwlHYw9Y0kp@59wUpsIfwaAA4wAmMCYjlXHixmIALNqgsyxyFmnzbsljwAJ/reCl0KkwRx2icbHhRqKJAWEE0Q72@gr7qkW0USUPtnPkCzJfnn@vfv/RqwhmY66cfpub4jjeOw1zXSFdqGDuX6pVtXUqAuQQclj0TP0kgQBNjdcsS9mA1cEdYA9PftISzepUcP1g/JyzYQbypv4ol/WXisEKv/6A47L3EoS3iZO/SPqZMnSlWO1am4umOpMBDSzy0kSfLpPXmSmmsxNYUXapJW8p1bhdelfLw2virjJVZsI6KXXhTx/Vxs1flVytX@@86XyPOOuvrSX/MtWX/tX1TbU8@GXsRi/@4AvXurmMdV1D7zdVyVtbQYj5aln@nDt98f7Ghv3p/AA) with optional chaining (doesn't work on TIO).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 138 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,l=len:sum(all(q&p^1for Q,P in zip(a,b[i:])for q,p in zip(Q,P[j:]))for i in range(l(b)-l(a)+1)for j in range(l(b[0])-l(a[0])+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VXLToQwFF3LVzSzMCXWpNfRDQl@g64rJhDBgXQYBnChP4@lw6MvBk2McWHSpHDO7bm3p6/qvd0dym2XhU8dj/fJS4xikhAe8rQMmrc9jjnHx8vqGbJDjR7JA8pL9JFXWESxPIj8Hj6SaoRFBCsELPG8R@u4fE0xx4l/zXHsX4GkCo1iNJJs34sAv2vTpm1QiJjHGKMEQUQQg6GX/xERlECobGC3YcREmoGjokWevqnGg51l5s/mnwWVdpZ31Wc0WZ9wQAR5vUOg1PsXHYLfcoiecWhwhE6Buv7gmzW30ctbRUkVo5oYdYopw6ldqjYUNEVXtJ6YLuRchY3to6/nYhJT1lgfWEm7xrvKtrcAfGu8mdmsf21@Th5W8/drfqMZDP8G/7DB27v5VBmHUJGfbkJYuaCW77WFCYOjTmWBp/PlqMC6vL4ACBUaeZHnyceVFCTtX1H5VgbeRVXnZYszLAifoE14vyEoDcMT4Hef)

### Ungolfed :

```python
def f(a,b):
  s=0 # intitialise the counter
  for i in range(len(b)-len(a)+1): # iterate through all the lines
    for j in range(len(b[0])-len(a[0])+1): # iterate through all the column
      # verify if the piece can fit
      if all(a[k][l]&b[i+k][j+l]^1 for k in range(len(a))for l in range(len(a[0]))):
        s+=1 # increase the counter
  return s  # return the counter
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVda4MwFH1efsWlD8NgBrnr9lJwfyRkYFncbMUWdQ/79S5JrTUf1g3G2MMgaLzn5NybE5McP7q3Q73u@xdVQJHkbEs3BKDNuH4WhwZKKGto8vpVJZWqky29M6@cpmiJJ9LOIwkuB57pjVSAsoC8qnR4L0Ulb7eiTHVvl1byGa3S3lXKKTXRyosaVTqK6nLTDPVHo7r3poa271TbtZCBIEIIzgAlA4HD235LpiEd4bZh2IYRI@gTz4oBeOpzB8cwywW/mv8iOGlX8Vh9XrP1aQc0iRiHcFLvX3QIf8shfsWhwRE@El39wbdgbmcvHyZKUzHuiPGo2GQ4D0t1hqKjGGO7iflMzsWw9/u46zmbxJf11gcX0i7hsbLDXwC/Nd7P7Ne/NL8ojov5zZrfOwbjv8E/bPD68bKrvE04kR9PQlw4oObPtZkJY6TOyQKP@ytSQXB4fSGgVbgkkhB7r7MdU@ZatXflhtwcm7LukiLRAGWwyp5WDFSWnQK0/wQ)

- `q&p^1` will be equal to 1 only if at most 1 of `q` and `p` is equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 165 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,d=b[z=0][L='length'],F=a.flat())=>b.flat().map((e,i)=>z+=b.slice(i/d,i/d+a[L]).flatMap((l,c)=>l.slice(i%d,i%d+a[0][L])).every((l,c,A)=>A[L]==F[L]&&!l|F[c]<l))|z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVdT8IwFH3vr5gPsDXU2aI@aUmIkSf8BbUJZXQwUzfCFhIRfzt2Y2PfTBNjfDApo9xzeu7tuax9EVsROhtvHV36wUIeXHqwBJqjBZ2zHcWcTamppL@MViZHEypsV4nIgpCO5unUfhVry5LI07HdgM7tUHmOtLyrBdKfgWBTDhPqU8xTyNE8lZF6mtSLSXEmDqEtt3LzltDQWBPHOkrpRD/7/Qu1nzCH3ysI97uDE/hhZEQyjB5EKEODGjPGMDIIRwYj6XfymwMWB3AySH2kC05glZgJ1sDjHJdwUs@S42fz54KFcRZvqq8ykvo4ICD14A@bQ37LHNxiztEMfOKUpVPHattKXbzJRAo6uKSDG3XSlbheXGkZKak1sUs5cUu6znDhr1JuXpt@VbHSC9KRsQtvqrjebvKt9dXM1fq79teIk878utPD3Fvy7@2Pent9C04mFt@4gnR21pGOI6j95GrZK2koMW/t8YWqJ6@dTF8IcIBndrhWXmSZz/6zbx5vX6kMOjKkyqEysBVKTyGEdwCcbkzbDTaPwlmlpHcQ36iBkrYKlparo/pORvpJODQopVqeDTkEH/DwCQ)

This feels too long.

Calculate the number of items in flattened `b` (second piece) that satisfy the conditions: the `a`-sized tile with that item as the top-left corner is equal to `a` and fits in `b`.

Credits: @EliteDaMyth (see comments)

Comment: putting z=0 in `d=b[z=0][L],` saves 2 bytes

Comment: similarly, putting L='length' in `d=b[z=0][L='length']` saves 2 more bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
≔⟦⟧ηＷＳ⊞ηιＷＳ⊞υ⁺ι⭆θ#Ｆη⊞υ#ＩΣ⭆υ⭆ι⬤η⬤ν№⁺π§§υ⁺κξ⁺μρ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU4xbsMwDNz1CsJcKEDlBzwFmTIUMJCxyGCkaSRUkR1LSvN7lXJsuFNvEI/kHXVn20/nofel7GJ010AfJwNWt@rHOn8BOoQxp2OaXLiS1tDlaMkacP8rsoHO50jOwGvz3o90N9Bgo7VYv4YJyG7iOm9VJ8pE@z4mOuYbbc7894zc3HlfQ9QSDOyHLLb5v1GG6RA@L09a6xrl28BT66W5GZh07RqugWa0pTAqRCWvQmZ8QSgunSxnxsyVIi8C3LR1x1Wz0sU2Q2zl7eF/AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as two newline-terminated lists of strings of `.` and any other character. Explanation:

```
≔⟦⟧ηＷＳ⊞ηι
```

Input piece 1.

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⁺ι⭆θ#Ｆη⊞υ#
```

Input piece 2, but pad it so that piece 1 can't accidentally wrap around (this is slightly golfier than calculating the positions that won't wrap around).

```
ＩΣ⭆υ⭆ι⬤η⬤ν№⁺π§§υ⁺κξ⁺μρ.
```

Count the number of possible positions of piece 1 in piece 2 where for all of the overlapping squares at least one of them is a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 108 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>[...b.matchAll(`(?=${a.replace(/./sg,c=>[`[
21]{${b.search`
`-a.search`
`+1}}`,'.',1][+c])})`)].length
```

```js
f = 

a=>b=>[...b.matchAll(`(?=${a.replace(/./sg,c=>[`[
21]{${b.search`
`-a.search`
`+1}}`,'.',1][+c])})`)].length

testcases = `
Piece 1: [[0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
Output: 4

Piece 1: [[1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 4

Piece 1: [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 42

Piece 1: [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
Piece 2: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output: 35

Piece 1: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
Piece 2: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
Output: 1

Piece 1: [[1]]
Piece 2: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
Output: 0 (Or any other non-integer value)
`.trim().split('\n\n').map(t => t.split('\n').map(l => JSON.parse(l.replace(/^.*:|\(.*$/g, '')))).map(([a, b, e]) => [a.map(l => l.map(n => '12'[n]).join('')).join('\n'), b.map(l => l.map(n => '12'[n]).join('')).join('\n'), e]);

testcases.forEach(([a, b, e]) => { console.log(f(a)(b) === e, f(a)(b)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Count[ListCorrelate@##,0,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVdS8MwFH3vryhRRCGDZOrLxsZk7kEQHM63GKSWTANdW7oMBqX967VfW9skbeeD4oMQ6G1ucs7J6c3txhKfbGMJblvJepLMvZ0ryCPfirkXBMyxBJudnUEEh/QiufeIEXLoRROHu2xshBZ8jyYv3mLvB2y75Z47W4mAux8r3@GCFPEz8x3LZoTDECw5s5kJ4vgtjsHIBIMpANAEJAvCLKJZFIGIQvDqAjo2limEIGuSMqVz5iWAHgRXgBowzDTAgmOxF4FlC3K@sgPuiwfX34kik@GkSIPpneNk8dNOpLmcOp2hEU0KTXhkEoKgiSk0CS6f@Ts1ihXDbEWaQfnA6ih3HpPywgOykixi1MhjlaXKd/JXgLXRmdfpk0aujxoH97Bh1GzDNfF/2Tb8W7ahU22TbELH3U3S0lTlwKXRB/gbBV7HgBoMSMvQhonUEzZwcANet1qvBrUI6Z3uKslmbfQyy1zSN8c9WvryurOoZYW/tV9mlvX3nU@bx738teoYalzH/67/rOvXt/KllC50jUvpw7inPbZ31RYXsEZ89fVbrmeHLKWfnjBR8SC1xZa@qKVY@1cdZX4B)